# How can you load a font (TTF) from a file using Core Text?

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon, osx-snow-leopard, core-text

Prior to OSX 10.6, ATSFontActivateFromFileSpecification/ATSFontActivateFromFileReference were available and could be used to load a font from a file.  I can't find anything similar in Core Text.

Answer (score 20):

You can get a `CTFontRef` from a font file by going via a `CGFontRef`:

```
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("/path/to/font"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL(url);
CGFontRef theCGFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider);
CTFontRef theCTFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(theCGFont);
CFRelease(theCGFont);
CFRelease(dataProvider);
CFRelease(url);

// do something with the CTFontRef here

CFRelease(theCTFont);
```

Comment: This doesn't work under Snow Leopard (confirmed by Apple) and you need to use `ATSFontActivateFromMemory()` on that version of OS X only.

Comment: Cannot confirm this. It works fine here on Snow Leopard.

Comment: This seems to be missing the size, matrix, and attributes arguments to CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont()

Answer (score 11):

It looks like `CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL` is the Core Text replacement.

Comment: And it makes for [shorter code than the Core Graphics route](https://gist.github.com/1696100).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an updated version of how to do this in 2020. Much simpler now. Used 12 as arbitrary type size.

```
let fontURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/font.otf")
let fd = CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL(fontURL as CFURL) as! [CTFontDescriptor]
let theCTFont = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(fd[0], 12.0, nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSURL *fontURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Crystal" withExtension:@"ttf"];
    assert(fontURL);
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    if (!CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fontURL, kCTFontManagerScopeProcess, &error))
    {
        CFShow(error);
        abort();
    }
```