# How do I get an NSFont object from a CGFont or CTFont object?

Tags: cocoa, core-text

I am dealing with loading a TTF from Resource only. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703085/how-can-you-load-a-font-ttf-from-a-file-using-core-text) helped me answer part 1. But now I need a NSFont from a CGFont or CTFont.

This is for a Mac only application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### How to get an NSFont from a CGFont

Use `CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont`.

#### How to get an NSFont from a CTFont

Do nothing. You already have one. [NSFont and CTFont are toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW19), so a CTFont is an NSFont and vice versa.

Comment: I thought toll-free bridged means only you can send messages of the other class to each other. Now I assume it also means you can use it directly as a substitute in place of the other.

Comment: Too bad Xcode still doesn't hint at this very well. If at all.