# Use CTFont object as NSFont object, bridge not working

Tags: ios, macos, core-text

I am trying to convert code that uses NSFont to code that uses CTFont (trying to make it cross-platform for macOS and iOS).

to According to the documentation, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942711/how-do-i-get-an-nsfont-object-from-a-cgfont-or-ctfont-object) post, I shouldn't have to do anything to make it work because there is a toll-free bridge between CTFontRef and NSFont.

Later, I am getting the error

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSFont * _Nonnull' with an lvalue of type 'CTFontRef' (aka 'const __CTFont *')
        convertedFont = [fontManager convertFont:convertedFont toNotHaveTrait:NSBoldFontMask];
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

OLD CODE: (keeping NSFontManager for now)

```
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
//            NSFont *font = static_cast<NSFont *>(inProperties[theKey]);
//            NSFontTraitMask fontTraits = [fontManager traitsOfFont:font];
//            NSFont *convertedFont = font;
```

NEW CODE:

```
CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)inProperties);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(descriptor, 0, NULL);
CFRelease(descriptor);
CTFontSymbolicTraits traits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font);
CTFontRef convertedFont = font;
```

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if it resolves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Toll-free bridge between `NSFont` and `CTFont` means the following:

Given an `NSFont` object, it can be directly casted as `CTFont` object.

```
NSFont *fontObj = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CTFontRef coreFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)(fontObj);
```

Given a `CTFont` object, it can be directly casted to a `NSFont` object.

```
CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)inProperties);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(descriptor, 0, NULL);
CFRelease(descriptor);
NSFont *nsFont = (__bridge NSFont *)(font);
```

I believe the mistake you are doing in your code is not casting your `NSFont` object to a `CTFont` object.

Please let me know if it resolves the problem