# Casting NSFont to CGFont — impossible?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-text

I try to cast NSFont to CGFont:

```
 var defaultFont: NSFont = NSFont.labelFont(ofSize: CGFloat(currentSize))
```

Like this:

```
 if let oldFont = defaultFont as? CGFont {...
```

No way, compiler says ”no”: `Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CGFont' will always succeed`. OK, let's try different way:

```
 let oldFont = defaultFont as CGFont
```

Nope. Compiler says ”no”: `'NSFont' is not convertible to 'CGFont'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?`. OK, let's use `as!`:

```
 let oldFont = defaultFont as! CGFont
```

Copmpiler says ”yes”!, But runtime error says: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

I tried initiate CGFont by name, but not all my fonts are "mounted in system", and font name could change from `Font-Name` to `Font_name` if its initiated by CGFont(_ name:CFString). It's risky.

Any help?

Comment: `NSFont` does not extend `CGFont` and they are not bridged. So no, you can't cast in any way.

Comment: I think they are bridged but Swift didn’t get the memo

Comment: @matt NSFont is bridged with CTFont, not CGFont.

Comment: `if let x = "Hello world" as? CGFont { }` also produces the compiler error “Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CGFont' will always succeed” – very strange.

Comment: You know what it could make to hobbyist programmer?

Comment: @Łukasz: Did you have a chance to check the answer? It would be nice to know if the suggested code works in your case.

Comment: Sorry, I have drowned for a while! It works pretty good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Feb/msg00177.html:

> > Given an NSFont object how can I extract or create a CGFontRef from it to use directly with CoreGraphics?
>
> You're close. Starting in (I think) Leopard, NSFont and CTFontRef (not CGFontRef) are toll-free bridged, so you should be able to use CTFontCopyGraphicsFont() to get a CGFontRef from an NSFont.

Example:

```
import CoreText

let defaultFont: NSFont = ...
let cgFont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont(defaultFont, nil)
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942711/how-do-i-get-an-nsfont-object-from-a-cgfont-or-ctfont-object

Comment: That's the other way around.