# Loading the ttf file in documents directory to give font to the Label?

Tags: ios, truetype, uifont

In my application I want to use the ttf in the documents directory. By referring to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312401/dynamic-custom-fonts-loader-in-ios?lq=1) I use below code to use the font from CGFontRef

```
+ (UIFont *)loadFontAtPath:(NSString*)path{
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];


// path is "/Users/............./Documents/bloktilt.ttf"
    if(data == nil){
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font. Data at path is null");
        return nil;
    }
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

NSString *fontName = (NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(font);
UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:15];

if(!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)){
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}
CFRelease(font);
CFRelease(provider);
return font1;
```

}

But the problem is that the above code is returning nil

Comment: ??? Is this for iOS?  It looks like OS X (the first line).

Comment: Regardless, these types are not tollfree bridged (as far as I know).  Use this method -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/6714885/1155387

Comment: @borrrden But the  above code is able to load the ttf file.Is there any other ways of retrieving the font from documents directory

Comment: Yes, use the accepted way on iOS (Just google iOS documents directory and you will find so many results)

Comment: @borrrden I've changed my question and find some other way of loading the font But Once again get stopped with the problem of tollfree bridging ie. I can't change the CGFontRef to UIFont. I explained it in the question

Comment: You have to register it BEFORE you try to make the UIFont

Comment: @borrrden That one is constraint for me I want to achieve it at the runtime and not before the runtime as registering has to be done manually before compiling the code

Comment: I'm talking about this -> CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont

Comment: @borrrden thanks for your guidance I finally get this

Comment: @borrrden whether CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont will register the font permanently to the device

Comment: Not sure but I don't think so

Comment: @borrrden that font lives up to the application instance's life time.

Comment: Have u also downloaded the ttf file through code in app ..

Comment: @Ankur Yes I have downloaded them through code